# Is there a non-income tax way of my father paying off my house?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, mortgage, california, gift-tax

My father will soon be moving in with me as he is retiring at the age of 77. We are wanting to pay off my mortgage ($250,000). But we want to do it all in my name because we don't want it to appear as an asset to him in case of any major issues arise, such as medical. Plus, if he ever needs in-home care, I would be able to do small contract work at the house instead of needing a full time job.

The other issue with putting it in his name is the property will be reassessed because I would have to sell it to him at fair-market-value and that is something we want to avoid because the housing market has exploded in that area again and the house is worth far more than what I initially got the mortgage for.

In the event I go before him, I am going to get a will just to make sure that the house is his.

---

With all of that said, the only thing I can find is the $14,000/year a person can give tax free. I am unable to find anything else that would allow more money. Is there anything else we can do? Even if it isn't the full amount, it should help with other possibilities.

If we did do the full $250,000 with taxes, what would the percentage of that be if say my taxable income normally was $100,000 (W2)?

Jokingly I was thinking of having my dad gift money to my aunts and uncles and then they gift it back to me, but I am sure that's just asking for trouble ;)

Any info would be most helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things come to mind:

- Gifts above $15,000 (raised from $14,000 in 2018) are not necessarily taxable. Gifted amounts over the $15,000 annual exclusion are applied toward the *lifetime* maximum of $11.4 Million. Only after that maximum has been reached do gifts become taxable.  Also, the tax is applied to the *giver*, not the *receiver*.
- Be *very* careful about hiding/gifting assets because it may impact Medicaid eligibility. Any gifts or transfers made within 5 years of applying for Medicaid may make the giver ineligible for a period of time. You may want to speak with an estate attorney.
- There are other ways to shelter assets from *liability*, such as setting up a trust.

Bottom line is: I would speak to an estate planning attorney to make sure everything is set up properly both from a legal and tax perspective.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. If there's an amount of $15,000 and anything over that amount is applied to the lifetime, then what is the point of the $15,000? Why isn't it just "Any amount under or at the lifetime max allowed"? And if I understand, he will be taxed even though he already paid taxes on that money? So he writes a check to me and then gets taxed X%? Or is that after the maximum of $5.4m?

Comment: That is after the $5.4MM. Basically I could give you $15k per year every year with nothing carrying forward. Additionally, I can give you up-to $5.4MM (nothing to do with the $15k per year) before you pay gift tax.

Comment: Oh! After all of the reading I did these last few months nothing seemed to state it clearly. Thanks a ton and also of course thank you D Stanley for your answer.

Comment: Yeah the tax code is pretty unreadable--even the "readable" stuff. It gets even more complex when you add in gifts to trusts. @TyCobb

Comment: Really can't resist the message to talk to an estate attorney. There are a lot of (not obvious) pitfalls to this stuff.

Comment: @dwizum Now that I know there is a valid path that fits our plans, I will be talking to one anyway and will double check there.

Comment: @TyCobb Gifting more than $15K per year is not completely "free"; the donor _must_ file an annual gift tax return (Form 709) telling the IRS that a gift of more than $15 K has been made, but the donor wishes to have it count towards his/her lifetime combined gift and estate tax exclusion (LCG&ETE) and so no gift tax is due right now. The form also has places for declaring how much of the LCG&ETE was used up on previous Forms 709s and how much is still left for future use. And Yes, the IRS reconciles the information with previous Forms 709. Keep copies of all Forms 709 with the _will_.

Comment: Basically the $15k/year lets people giving "normal" gifts not have to worry about the paperwork or pay taxes. But the cap exists to keep people from giving large "gifts" while they are alive to avoid paying the estate tax (which kicks in at $5.4m and is not-so-coincidentally the level that the gift tax kicks in at)